# Erro de tradução - Análise Publicações de baixa qualidade

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

O botão "Parece OK" ou "Parece legal" em `Analisar|Publicações de baixa qualidade` está em inglês
[image: Erro de tradução]

Comment: Foi uma mudança recente no sistema (muita gente reclamava de ter que dizer "looks good" pra coisas apenas "passáveis"). Já avisei o Gabe, ele tem acesso às traduções e ficou de arrumar.